# Should I use 'with' when talking about inanimate objects?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

My question is in relation to the following example (and any equivalent situations):

> My package from Amazon has arrived and is with my mom.

Would it be better to say for instance:

> My package from Amazon has arrived and my mom has it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My package from Amazon has arrived and is with my mom.

It's not wrong but your second sentence would be a lot more common.

"With" would probably used more often when talking about delivering/transporting as in

> I bought you a present. I'm sending it with mom since she's coming to see you next week

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in saying that an item of property is 'with' the person who is looking after it.

Comment: I only said that one would probably be used a lot more often.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+with+him%2C+he+has+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20with%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20has%20it%3B%2Cc0